# MongoDB: find elements by value of specific element of subarray

Tags: mongodb

I have collection with following document structure:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    statuses: [
      {
        id:3, r:true, date:2016-02-01
      },
      {
        id:2, r:false, date:2015-02-02
      },
      {
        id:3, r:false, date:2015-02-03
      }

   ]
}
```

How to find all elements from collection where r=false in LAST status where id=3.

If I could sort statuses by date descending, filter it by id=3 and take the first element... Maybe there is smarter way :)

Comment: Do you want the whole record to be returned or only the array part where `id:3` and `status:false`?

Comment: I want all documents matching that criteria. Number of that documents will also help me to continue solving my problem

Comment: This document does not match the given criteria: the last status for id 3 is from 2016-02-01, and `r==true` there. Please refine your requirements.

Comment: That's right. Given JSON is just a sample document. All the documents have an array of statuses and every status has given attributes. This array represents some status change. Every status change has flag "r". I want to "select" all documents where on last switch to status id 3, r flag was not set. I hope i'm clear now

Comment: Have you tried using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) or are you asking an alternative to aggregation ? Also,  If you are querying this frequently, you may want to reconsider your schema.